# How to implement Basic Authentication and Authorization in a .net core rest service?

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, authorization

I'm new to the .NET Core REST API. This is my first shot on implementing basic authentication and authorization after. So far it's working.

I'd like to know whether this is done properly. Any comment or suggestion for improvement ist highly appreciated.

Key compontents are an authentication middleware and an usernames handler.

In the  authentication middleware username and password passed by the authorization header are checked against the valid logins.

If the login is valid, a new identity is added to the the user object with the label set to the passed in username (plus a fudge in front of it).

In the usernames handler this new identity is being used to authorize the user.

Here's the relevant piesces of code:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logins": {
    "test": "B0Lo8tsQpKs=",
    "tryme": "B0Lo8tsQpKs="
  },
  "Policies": {
    "UserPolicySnrCounter": "test,tryme"
  }
}
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var policies = Configuration.GetSection("Policies");

    ...

    services.AddAuthentication().AddCustomAuth(options => {});

    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesHandler>();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("PolicySnrCounter", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserNamesRequirement(policies.GetValue<string>("UserPolicySnrCounter"))));
    });               
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationMiddleware>(Configuration.GetSection("Logins"));

    ...                   
}
```

AuthenticationMiddleware

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Basic"))
    {

    string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();

    string usernamePassword = _encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));    

    int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

    var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
    var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

    var loginPassword = _logins.GetValue<string>(username);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginPassword))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
        loginPassword = Crypto.Decrypt(loginPassword);
    }

    if (password == loginPassword)
    {
        context.User.AddIdentity(new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity() { Label = "CustomAuth" + username });
        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    // no authorization header
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
    return;
}
```

}

UserNamesHandler

```
public class UserNamesHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNamesRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNamesRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userNames = (UserNamesRequirement)context.Requirements.FirstOrDefault();
        var currentUserClaimsIdentity = context.User.Identities.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Label != null && p.Label.StartsWith("CustomAuth"));

    if (userNames != null && currentUserClaimsIdentity != null)
    {
        var names = userNames.UserNames[0].Split(',').ToList();
        var currentUser = currentUserClaimsIdentity.Label.Replace("CustomAuth", "");

        if (names.Any(s => s.Equals(currentUser)))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. It might be more appropriate for [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: While creating the project, you can select basic authentication in Visual studio. It will auto generate all the code you need.

Comment: Give a look [here](https://github.com/msmolka/ZNetCS.AspNetCore.Authentication.Basic). I used it and It works very well!